# SugarCRM Report: Can You Measure The Average Length Of Your Sales Cycle In A Report

Tags: report, analytics, crm, sugarcrm

I'm interested in creating a report in SugarCRM that allows me to see the average amount of time it takes for a lead to go through the sales cycle and become a won opportunity.

The report would only take into account leads that actually managed to make it through the funnel, and it would ignore those leads that never eventually became won-opportunities

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: tried creating a report using the leads and opportunities modules, but could not find anything in the interface that got close to being able to calculate a time of transition between states and then average that time out.